# Themes not visible in Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: unity, themes, tweak

[THIS](http://www.ubuntuthemes.org/downloads/aurora-3-16/) is the theme I'd like to install. What I've done so far:

1. Extracted Dark-Aurora folder from the archive.
2. Copied that folder to `~/usr/share/themes`.
3. Created `/home/[user-name]/.themes` folder and copied Dark-Aurora there too.
4. Opened Unity Tweak Tool, clicked on Theme.
5. Only the three default themes (Ambiance, Highcontrast and Radiance) are there). Dark-aurora is nowhere to be found.

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why wouldn't show, but I'm pretty sure you wouldn't like the results of a gtk 3.16 theme on gnome 3.20 anyways, assuming you're using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did the theme come with a `readme.txt`?

Comment: Remove from one location.  Also let me know what is the contents of /usr/share/themes/Dark-Aurora?

Comment: Dark-Aurora has gnome-shell folder inside so I assumed it would be compatible with Gnome.

Comment: Inside Dark-Aurora there are the following folders: `gnome-shell`, `gtk-2.0`, `gtk-3.0` and `index.theme` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After extracting the archive, you'll find **Aurora** and **Dark Aurora** folders there. You have to put them in either `~/.local/share/themes` or `/usr/share/themes` directory.

However, I saw that they don't appear in Unity Tweak Tool. The solution is using **Gnome Tweak Tool** to set the theme.

To install it -

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open and set the theme from Appearance Section.

**Update after further information** It appeared OP's `.local` folder was owned by root. To get the ownership use `sudo chown -r your-user-name ~/.local` before copying the theme folder. Then use `cp` without using `sudo`.

Comment: `sudo cp -r Downloads/Dark-Aurora/ ~/.local/share/themes/Dark-aurora
` but still it is not shown in GTT.

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman I didn't get you. I said in the answer that since this theme is incompatible, it will not be shown in Unity Tweak tool. But Gnome tweak tool will show it. Also, you don't need `sudo`. remove the folder by going to `~/.local/share/themes/` and paste them as normal user

Comment: GTT = Gnome Tweak Tool. And I can't access `./local` wihout root access.

Comment: If you cant access `.local` in your home, that means you have lost ownership of that folder and did bad things. You need to do `sudo chown -r your-user-name ~/.local` first

Comment: Good lord it worked. Yes, claiming ownership of those folders made the themes available.

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman you should have told me that way before. good that it worked. basically nothing in your home folder should be owned by root

Answer (score 0):

sometimes if your theme folder does not contain gnome-shell and gtk folders, it means that it only contains icons and must be put in /usr/share/icons or /home/username/.icons instead.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is still relevant but: on ubuntu 18.04 is installed libgtk-3.22. I had a theme directory (in ~/.themes) with subdir gtk-3.16 and gtk-3.22, and tweak/userthemes tool didn't list the theme. But when I made a link called gtk-3.0 pointing to the gtk-3.16 directory, the theme *was* shown. (And it was reading the theme from the gtk-3.22 directory) So yes...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have also created a link with the name `gtk-3.22` for `gtk3.0` and it worked.

```
~/.themes$ ls
cinnamon  COPYING  gnome-shell  gtk-2.0  gtk-3.0  index.theme  metacity-1  Mojave-light  Mojave-light-alt  plank  xfwm4

~/.themes$  ln -s ~/.themes/gtk-3.0 gtk-3.22
```