# Cannot claim ownership of a folder

Tags: unity, permissions, themes, ownership

I downloaded a .tar.gz package (new theme for my Ubuntu 16.04), extracted it and tried to copy-paste file into `usr/share/themes`, but apparently this folder is owned by root. After some research ([this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819277/themes-not-visible-in-unity-tweak-tool)) I came up with an idea: `sudo chown -R username ~/.share` and got the message that such file or directory doesn't exist. So I tried another method `sudo chown -R username:username share` followed by the same message; this file or directory doesn't exist.

Without ownership I cannot install new theme, but obviously I'm doing something wrong. If anyone can help me I'd be delighted.

Comment: Please don't `chown` that directory. Use `sudo cp` or `sudo -i nautilus` if you really need to place files there

Comment: I actually used `sudo -i nautilus` and copied a file inside desired folder. Now it is there, but is unreadable. Working on it right now. Thank you so much, Zanna!

Comment: no worries, hope it works out for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) I found a solution. If anyone experiences the same problem, here is what you should do.

First of all, use `sudo -i nautilus` in order to gain `root` privileges. Copy extracted theme files into `usr/share/themes` (or `/.local/share/themes` if that's where those files of yours belong). By doing this you only copy those files, but they are still useless.

Next, right click the folder and choose "Properties". You have to open a tag named "Permission". You will (most likely) see that Owner is `root` and Access is "Create and delete files". That's OK, leave it be. Next one is Group and once again `root` is mentioned. This time set Access to "Access files". Finally, with Others you should also choose Access to be "Access files".

Exit nautilus. You might need to close all windows or even restart system. After this operation, open Gnome Tweak Tool. If you don't have it, run `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`. Under Appearance tab you'll see GTK+ Theme option. This is where your new theme can be found.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

(for example the downloaded file is `my_theme.tar.gz` and the working folder is `~/Downloads`)

```
gunzip my_theme.tar.gz
tar -xvf my_theme.tar
```

(now we got suppose a folder my_theme)
(after this we need to copy it to the theme-folder)

```
sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/my_theme /usr/share/themes/
```

That's all.